# Using PreAuthorize for resource security with JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I have successfully implemented JWT-authentication for my Rest-API in Java Spring Boot. Only with a valid JWT-token users can make requests to my secured endpoints. But I need to find a way so that users can only access the resources they own.

If user "foobar" with ID 1 is authenticated, he should only be able to access GET /users/1 and /users?name=foobar. /users/2 should return an error 403.

Currently I have a solution by using `@PreAuthorize`.

I have made a class **UserResourceValidator.java**:

```
package com.example.demo.auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.example.demo.repositories.UserRepository;


@Component
public class UserResourceValidator {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public boolean isResourceOwner(Authentication authentication, Integer resourceId) {
        User user = userRepository.findByName(authentication.getName()).orElse(null);
        
        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return user.getId() == resourceId;
    }
}
```

In my **UserService.java** I use the following `@PreAuthorize` annotation:

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.auth.UserResourceValidator;
import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.example.demo.repositories.UserRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserResourceValidator userResourceValidator;
    
    public boolean userExists(String name) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByName(name);
        return user.isPresent();
    }
    
    public User createUser(User user) {
        if (userExists(user.getName())) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    
    @PreAuthorize("@userResourceValidator.isResourceOwner(authentication, #id)")
    public User getUserById(Integer id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    
    @PreAuthorize("#name == authentication.principal.toString()")
    public User getUserByName(String name) {
        return userRepository.findByName(name).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

This works fine. But I was wondering if there is a better solution?

Also, `isResourceOwner` currently only checks if the ID of the authenticated user matches with the ID of the resource. This will work if the requested resource is an User-object, but what if I want to check if a Book with id 123 belongs to user 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PostLoad** lifecycle events from the persistent object. Suppose you have different access based on different entities. For that reason, you can have an interface like `IOwner`. For simplicity, I'm adding a method that returns a user object of the actual owner. You can have different methods like (owners, roles, etc).

```java
public interface IOwner {
    User getOwner();
}
```

Now you can implement the interface in `Book.class`. And return the appropriate owner for that Book object.
You also need to add `EntityListeners` to your entity like this.

```java
@EntityListeners(OwnershipListener.class)
public class Book implements IOwner {
    // entities and methods
}
```

**OwnershipListener.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class OwnershipListener implements ConfigurableObject {

    @PostLoad
    public void afterLoad(Object target) {
        Assert.notNull(target, "Entity must not be null!");

        if (target instanceof IOwner) {
            User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            if (!((IOwner) target).getOwner().equals(user)) {
                // TODO throw your custom exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note you have to add **@EnableJpaAuditing** in your main class as well.